# Error in Reading Json String with backslash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, backslash

I have Converted a C# class in Json Object after it  I stringify that json Object then it converts with backslash(escaping character)  and when i used following code to read the json string it gives me undefined message in alert .

```
<script>



    var jsString = { "JsonString": ["{\"reachoutid\":1,\"user_ID\":1,\"question\":\"Best CMS in Microsoft  .Net\",\"anonymous\":false,\"shared\":false,\"create_date\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"update_date\":\"\\/Date(1327300086183)\\/\",\"status\":0,\"start_date\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"end_Date\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"reachoutfactorsList\":null,\"reachoutchoicesList\":[{\"reachoutid\":0,\"choice_ID\":4,\"orders\":0,\"description\":\"Sitecore\",\"preachOutID\":0,\"pchoice_ID\":4,\"porders\":0,\"pdescription\":\"Sitecore\"},{\"reachoutid\":0,\"choice_ID\":5,\"orders\":0,\"description\":\".Net Nuke \",\"preachOutID\":0,\"pchoice_ID\":5,\"porders\":0,\"pdescription\":\".Net Nuke \"},{\"reachoutid\":0,\"choice_ID\":6,\"orders\":0,\"description\":\"Drupal\",\"preachOutID\":0,\"pchoice_ID\":6,\"porders\":0,\"pdescription\":\"Drupal\"}],\"detail\":\"Write more text to check progress bar work properly.\",\"set_Listof_Tags\":null,\"tag\":null,\"get_Listof_Tags\":null,\"userstatus\":null,\"actType\":\"RO\"}"], "_getList_MyActivities": null, "_getList_MyPeersActivities": null, "userID": 1 }

    for (i = 0; jsString.JsonString.length > i; i++) 
    {

        alert(jsString.JsonString[i].reachoutid);

        //"Giving Undefined Message "

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON shouldn't be quoted. When it is, JS interprets is as a string instead of an object

```
var jsObject = { "JsonString": [{"reachoutid":1,"user_ID":1,"question":"Best CMS in Microsoft  .Net","anonymous":false,"shared":false}]} // etc.
```

Comment: But when i converted my C# class object into Json   like this it convert it with                                           Backslash , JavaScriptSerializer objSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        JSONString = objSerializer.Serialize(_ReachOut);

Comment: @Shailesh what type of object is `_ReachOut`?

Comment: Thanks for ur help  ...got solution alert( JSON.parse(jsString.JsonString[i]).reachoutid )

Comment: JavaScript Object != JSON.

JSON is a string.  This answer fundamentally doesn't understand the differences between the two.  Billy's answer is far more correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is stored as a string, not as a native object. To convert it back, change your `alert( ... )` line to use `JSON.parse( ... )` like this:

```
    alert( JSON.parse(jsString.JsonString[i]).reachoutid )
```